# Can I substitute a main verb with an auxiliary verb in a subordinate clause if it has an object after?

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs, subordinate-clauses, complex-sentences, single-word-requests

There are no auxiliary verbs in my language, so I often struggle using them in English. If I want to substitute a main verb in a subordinate clause of a complex sentence, because it's the same as in the main clause, can it be followed by an object? As in "I washed my car faster than she DID (?) hers."

Comment: Yes you can. In fact, you might *need* to in your example if you want to make it clear that she washed ***her*** car rather than yours. Given no other context, that "default" assumption (that the object of ***washed*** is the same in both cases) would normally apply. Certainly I'd assume only one car ever got washed in, say, *I washed my car this morning faster than she did last week.*

Comment: Yes, because you can think of *washed* as *did wash*; so using only *did* in the second clause is just a matter of eliding *wash*. You aren't really susbtituting an auxiliary verb in the second clause as leaving out the lexical verb.